# Using push notifications on Heroku

Tags: ios, node.js, heroku, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I am looking for the simplest way to use push notifications to users from a Parse-Server app on Heroku. Just in case, this is for an iOS app.

Any tip or suggestion would be appreciated.

I used have code working on parse.com. But it does not seem to be working any more.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look on this hope it works [Traversy media PUSH Notification](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HlYFW2zaYQM)
He shows on pc i think this might work on mobile also ,if not the library he is using must have your solution

Comment: I followed the tutorial you mentioned and now have something working. I now need to go for the next step and make something work sending notifications to an iOS app. Would you have any suggestion?